# Graphical changelog in mercurial's hgwebdir.cgi

Tags: mercurial, hgweb

I have a set of mercurial repositories being served online with hgwebdir.cgi. I would like to be able to show a graphical representation of the branches and merges in the same way that [this site](http://hg.serpentine.com/mercurial/book/graph) does. I can't seem to find any reference to how to do that though. Does the functionality only exist in hgweb and not hgwebdir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until version 1.1 comes out (in a few days) you'd need to clone and install from the [Mercurial crew respository](http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/)

Answer (score 3):

This future will be enabled in next release, try use develop version from repo.

In console u can use [glog extension](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/GraphlogExtension)